# How can I instruct a program (.exe) on Windows to use a different gateway?

Tags: windows-10, networking

Using Windows10 I want one of my programs **not** to use the default gateway but I want to define a custom gateway for it.

How can I do this?

The program doesn't support proxy or VPN, and I really just want to make it using a custom gateway.

My computer does have only one network interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third-party tool like [ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip). But note, that will not be possible without a second network adapter. You can add several gateways to the same adapter, but you can not bid application to those gateways directly. Therefore you have to either use a second network adapter (e.g. a USB network adapter, they are very inexpensive) or a virtual network adapter (which I haven't tried myself yet).

As far as I know, you can add a second IP if your network adapter is configured manually via `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` go to your network adapter -> properties -> IP-Protokoll (4 or 6 depending on what you use) then to "advanced". Here you can add IP addresses and gateways you can use to ForceBind:

[image]